# Uploading files using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

So I am trying to upload a file using selenium and I know you can do this using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myfile")).sendKeys("/filepath");
```

explained here: http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload

The issue is that the input tag Im sending it to is invisible and throw an `ElementNotVisibleException`

for this tag:

```
<input id ="myfile" class="ussr-component-file-uploader-target-file ussr-component-file-uploader-file ussr-helper-display-none" type="file" accept="video/*">
```

since the type is not hidden not sure how I would use the JavascriptExecuter to make it visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `ussr-helper-display-none` class from the element.

If the page uses jQuery, this would be easy:

```
$("#myfile").removeClass("ussr-helper-display-none");
```

then, invoke your `.sendKeys()`

If the page doesn't have jQuery, then:

```
document.getElementById('myfile').className = "ussr-component-file-uploader-target-file ussr-component-file-uploader-file";
```